# Regex in java trouble

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to set a condition that a string has to match the number 354 plus any whitespace character plus any characters afterwards. For example: the following string `"354 adfjdakl"` would work but `"354asl;dfa"` should not.

I've made a regex that is equal to `String regex="354\\s+.*"` however when I run `string.match(regex)` it does not give me the right answer. What's the correct format for specifying such a string?

Comment: Mind showing some code, with input you're giving and output you're getting? And what is your expected output? That regex seems to be fine as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a correct regex. It should work appropriately.

```
String regex = "354\\s.+";
```

See it in action here: http://rubular.com/r/YwrVPD1rwU
And here in Java: http://ideone.com/CA1uAg

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    String regex = "354\\s.+";
    System.out.println("354 adfjdakl".matches(regex));
    System.out.println("354asl;dfa".matches(regex));
}
```

Output:

```
true
false
```

Comment: Okay then the problem is not with my regex. Thanks for the input nevertheless

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern `(\\d+)\\s?.*`

```
String regex="(354)\\s?.*"
```

Comment: I believe the question asked specifically for the number 354. Your pattern would match any number.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for any **one** whitespace character after the 354, the correct regex would be

```
354\s\S+
```